# gaierror at /accounts/social/signup/ - Django allauth twitter signup

Tags: django, google-app-engine, twitter, django-allauth

I have a [django website](http://ofon123.appspot.com) hosted in Google App Engine. And am using allauth to login to my app with Twitter. When a user tries to sign up to the app, it is redirected to twitter for authorization and after authorizing, it is redirected to `http://ofon123.appspot.com/accounts/social/signup/` where it asks to provide Username(already filled) and email(blank) in a form. On submitting the form, I get this error in the same url:

```
gaierror at /accounts/social/signup/
[Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://ofon123.appspot.com/accounts/social/signup/
Django Version: 1.4.3
Exception Type: gaierror
Exception Value:    
[Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
Exception Location: /base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/remote_socket/_remote_socket.py in _ResolveName, line 231
Python Executable:  /base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/python
Python Version: 2.7.5
Python Path:    
['/base/data/home/apps/s~ofon123/1.371600740837279431/apps',
 '/base/data/home/apps/s~ofon123/1.371600740837279431',
 '/base/data/home/apps/s~ofon123/1.371600740837279431',
 '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python27.zip',
 '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7',
 '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1',
 '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/MySQLdb-1.2.4b4',
 '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/PIL-1.1.7',
 '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/PIL-1.1.7/PIL',
 '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4',
 '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/protorpc-1.0',
 '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3',
 '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webob-1.1.1',
 '/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/yaml-3.10']
Server time:    Wed, 13 Nov 2013 05:55:30 +0000
```

My callback url in twitter application setting is:

```
Callback URL: http://ofon123.appspot.com
```

The user is actually signed up for the app despite the error(I can see it in my social accounts from django administration).

How do I get rid of this error?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Finally solved this way...

I was allowing verification email to be sent to the new user. This was enabled by the line in settings.py `ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "optional"`This is where allauth used the socket api to connect to smtp but was not able to connect. First, I thought setting it to optional, allauth would not try to send email which is what I want in the first phase of the project. But I found that I had to set `ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "none"` to disable allauth to send verification email. This solved my current problem.

Comment: This solution doesn't solve the problem. It only avoids it. In my case I have the same problem but I need to send verification e-mails. Is there any other way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

From the error message it looks like allauth is using the socket api to connect somewhere, but the socket isn't able to connect.  You probably want to have an exception handler catch the exception and dump a stack trace (use logging.exception()) to isolate where that's happening.

You'll probably need to patch allauth to work with GAE's sockets.  You'll want to read up on the limitations of GAE's sockets:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sockets/

Comment: Yes, allauth was using the socket api to connect to smtp for sending e-mail to the user but wasn't able to connect thus throwing an error. I disabled that in the settings.